# set variable from specific line

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I have a txt file :

```
[STATION NUMBER]
ST = 9992
[IP CONFIGURATIONS]
COMP1 = 128.1.7.9
COMP2 = 128.1.7.8
COMP3 = 128.1.7.7
```

I want to set varibles like this:

```
ST=9992
RFS=128.1.7.9
BOS=128.1.7.8
POS=128.1.7.7
```

i've tried to write something but I can't figure out how to proccess on line at a time:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3" %%a in (ipsetting.txt) do echo %%c
```

if I use "SKIP=1" it gives me the second line and also third forth and etc..:

```
9992
128.1.7.9
128.1.7.8
128.1.7.7
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims== " %%i in ('find "=" ipsetting.txt') do set %%i=%%j
```

First trick: include only needed files (the lines, that have a `=`) (`find "="`)

second trick: eliminate spaces (with delims): use `=` and Space () as delimiters (multiple delimiters are treated as one, so in `ST = 9992` token 1 is `ST` without trailing space and token 2 is `9992` without leading space)

Comment: fantastic! also can skip line by using 'eol' with ';' right?

Comment: it will skip lines, that start with `;`. Are there any?